# Foursquare Checkins API

Tags: api, foursquare

What are the informations from a user that are avaible, by default, for users that are not his "friend"s ?

Can i have the list of "checkins" from any Foursquare user only by making API requests ? 
What kind of information about a user i can fetch, without having him as my friend (friend of the account used to perform the API requests) on foursquare ?

On linkedin, for example, i could fetch his Company, but if the user used to perform the API requests had this user as a friend, i could fetch the whole "company history" . Is there any restriction like this one on foursquare ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this out yourself at the API Explorer to see: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/1234

As you can see, even if you're not friends with this user, you can see their name, friends' names, contact info (Twitter/Facebook), and checkin counts, *but not the actual checkins themselves*. You will need to be friends with this user to see their checkin history.

Note that if you make this request without authentication (e.g., https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/1234 with no oauth_token ) then you can't see any information about them.